# gradle publishing Jar with source files and dependencies in POM

Tags: java, gradle, documentation

I am using gradle and I want to create a `.jar` with source files when doing a `publishToMavenLocal`.  I have got that to work easily:

```
task jarWithSources(type: Jar) {
    from sourceSets.main.output
    if (gradle.startParameter.taskNames.any{it == "publishToMavenLocal"}) {
        from sourceSets.main.allJava
    }
}

publishing {
    publications {
        // publish the data_deposit jar as a standalone artifact
        mavenJar(MavenPublication) {
            artifact jarWithSources
            artifactId "${jar.baseName}_jar"
            version project.version
        }
    }
    repositories {
        maven { ... }
    }
}
```

However the `pom.xml` is missing the dependencies.

If I use this:

```
publishing {
    publications {
        // publish the data_deposit jar as a standalone artifact
        mavenJar(MavenPublication) {
            // artifact jarWithSources    // Stopped using this
            from components.java          // Have added this
            artifactId "${jar.baseName}_jar"
            version project.version
        }
    }
    repositories {
        maven { ... }
    }
}
```

Where this is only that one change in the `MavenPublication`, then I get the full `pom.xml` but no source of course.  I cannot find a way to include both `artifact jarWithSources` and `from components.java`.  The error is:

```
Invalid publication 'mavenJar': multiple artifacts with the identical extension and classifier ('jar', 'null').
```

Implying that `from components.java` is of `type: Jar` also.

Can anyone advise how I can get all this to work?

Now to end this question, I have to say that `Gradle` has a very very very steep learning curve.  Its a computer language (DSL) so must be deterministic though sometimes I wonder.  I do not have the knowledge to understand how (for example) `from components.java` works (#1).  For as much documentation as there is (such as http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/publishing_maven.html and the DSL guide), it isn't very clear.  I think the documentation could be a lot richer.  And there needs to be a chapter on "getting it".  There is some paradigm shift that one seems to need to understand!

#1 - as best I understand this gives you what is at http://www.gradle.org/docs/nightly/userguide/java_plugin.html#sec:java_plugin_and_dependency_management but how does that work with a `from` and in the context of a `MavenPublication`?

Comment: "a very very very steep learning curve" i would add a few very myself. Too much magic and bad naming

Comment: have the same problem about obfuscated jars

Answer (score 8):

[Here](https://github.com/Opalo/stackoverflow/tree/master/27894707) you can find working example, it's enough to invoke `gradle clean publishToMavenLocal` to have artifacts build and published to maven local maven repo (artifact will be taken from folder name version number is *unspecified*).

It seems that `build.gradle` file should be slightly altered. Is the project published, may I have a try?

At the beginning gradle indeed seems to be difficult, but after configuring first projects you'll quickly catch it.

**EDIT** (after discussion in comments)

To include both sources and compiled classes in a single jar add the following piece of code to `build.gradle`:

```
jar { 
   from sourceSets.main.output
   from sourceSets.main.allJava
}
```

And remove task `sourceJar` and `artifact` section from `publications`. It works however including both sources and compiled classes is quit unusual and not a good idea.

Dependencies are added automatically installed `pom.xml` - see for *guice*. I've updated project on GitHub.

Comment: Yes, that's good - read the error and see there is a classifier clash.  And so choose a different classifier.  However I actually want the sources to be in the same jar to help with debugging.  I haven't tried this but I imagine if you depend on the sources jar also then the same debugging benefit would be gained.  Although this would work it means having to add the dependency just for development.  I guess you could guard it to only happen when developing but then that gets ugly, especially if you have heaps of them.  So want - sources in the same jar AND have the dependencies in the pom.

Comment: Ok, will try that on tomorrow.

Comment: Thanks.  I re-read my comment and it sounds a bit rude.  I meant to say that I should have read the error message more closely to realise it was a classifier clash.  So thanks for pointing that out.  But yes I need a different result!

Comment: @HankCa is that what You're looking for?

Comment: Hi @Opal, sorry my contract finished up and I've been busy doing family stuff.  I'll get back to this shortly.

Comment: Hi @Opal, not quite right - that does add source to the jar but I want the source to only be in the `<project>-jar.jar` when performing a `publishToMavenLocal`.  Putting the guard `if (gradle.startParameter.taskNames.any{it == "publishToMavenLocal"}) {` as seen in the question would seem to only include the sources when `publishToMavenLocal`, but I want the `jar {` block like you have but only for the `<project>-jar.jar`.  cont ...

Comment: You can see in the question I tried to have a `mavenJar(MavenPublication) {
            artifact jarWithSources` but without the `from components.java` which can't seem to exist with `artifact jarWithSources`, the dependencies aren't included in the `.pom`.

Comment: Hi @Opal I forked your repo, modified with what I had and have created a pull request for you - https://github.com/Opalo/stackoverflow/pull/1.

Comment: For me? It was your question. Next time please be a bit more precise. You asked a question, I answered, "Ok, but I wanted", the I answered for the second time, "Not quite right". And I didn't even got any points for the time spent on it. Be precise. Please.

Comment: Hi @Opal I appreciate your time and haven't upvoted it yet as you haven't answered the question.  After I received your feedback it seems it might not have been clear enough. I thought my comments were helping you understand the problem better so you could help me find an answer.

Comment: Sorry, I'm lost. Is the question answered or not?

Comment: No sorry :(.  Please see the changes I made to the `build.gradle` in my fork of the repo (or your repo after a merge).  In that is the normal `mavenJava` MavenPublication and a new `mavenJar` used to create the '<project>-jar.jar` artifact.  The former is NOT to include the sources but the latter is.  Both should include the .classes and their `.pom`s should contain the dependencies.  I can either get the `<project>-jar.jar` to contain the sources OR the dependencies (but not both).  The location in the `build.gradle` where this choice is made is indicated.

Comment: Ok, will have a look at it later on ;)